# Обновление статуса вебхука

Tags: php

Помогите разобраться с кодом PHP. Выдает ответ - 405. Статус Вебхука не меняется. Что я делаю неправильно?

```
$curl = curl_init();
$query_api_ms='https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/webhook/6e4209ed-f6d8-11e7-7a69-971100055916';
$USERAGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36';
$wh_upd = 
'{
"enabled": false
}';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$userName:$userPassword");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $USERAGENT);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query_api_ms);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'CURLOPT_PUT'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($wh_upd))); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $wh_upd); 
curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` установлена как строка `'CURLOPT_PUT'`, а не константа. Лучше использовать `guzzlehttp/guzzle`.